Resampling and finding area of pixels simultaneoulsy using terra R package
Consider I have a 30m binary raster with values 0 and 1, where 1 is categorical and is a land cover type. I would like to resample this raster to 1km such that the resulting raster has pixel values of the proportion of the 1km pixel that is covered by pixel values=1 in the 30m raster. See example below where the larger pixel is made of 6 smaller pixels with two smaller pixels having value 1 (and remaining are 0), such that the resulting pixel has value of 2/6=0.33 ie 33% of the larger pixel is of cover type 1.

I have tried using terra::resample() with method="sum". However I do not understand the output.
r1 <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, vals=10) #coarse resolution raster with generic pixel values

r2 <- rast(ncol=100, nrow=100, vals=0) #fine resolution raster
r2[c(1,109, 10000, 23, 899, 6143, 90)]<-1 #assigning random cells value=1

x<- resample(r2, r1, "sum")

In the image below, the first panel is coarser resolution r1, second is finer resolution r2 and the last is the resampled output. What I do not understand is what are the pixel values int he resampled output 0,1,2? How can I proceed?


From the help: sum: the weighted sum of all non-NA contributing grid cells.. Your fine raster has 0 and 1, sum of contributing cells is 1( or 2 respectively), because 0+0+ ... +0+1 = 1. Try to use average instead of sum.

You are right, I should use average!
